# Pylint not working when used as pre-commit hook in github

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, github

I am trying to use the following pre-commit hook to check my code quality. 
https://github.com/sebdah/git-pylint-commit-hook

I followed the instruction and installed it but it's displaying me a 0 score for all file. ex.

```
Running pylint on make_postreq.py (file 5/15).. 0/10.00  FAILED ************* Module make_postreq
```

Whereas if I run `pylint` from the console, I get a decent score.

```
Global evaluation
Your code has been rated at 8.75/10 (previous run: 8.75/10, +0.00)
```

I feel it might be a configuration issue, but can't seem to make it work. 
Or is there some other way we can check our Python code quality before committing in GitHub?

Comment: We're going to need a bit more information. Can you show the relevant `.pylintrc`? Does running from the console cover `make_postreq.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may be caused by setting the `files-output` parameter in your pylintrc to `yes`.  I just ran into this where I transferred a configuration file over.  The result processing in `git-pylint-commit-hook` requires that `pylint` print the final status to stdout, which is suppressed with `files-output`.

Comment: depricated in pylint > 2.0 https://docs.pylint.org/en/latest/whatsnew/changelog.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Try to

1. set 'reports=yes' in [REPORTS] section
2. don't disable 'RP0004'